# Ransack search multiple start_with values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Is it possible with Ransack to search *starts with* using an array of values?

For example, something like `Product.search(name_start: %w(a b))` would return all products whose name starts with 'a' or 'b'.

Alternatively, I have a scope, but was not able to figure out how to connect it using ransacker or ransackable_scopes.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there does not appear to be a *starts_with* option that accepts an array. However, as of August 19, 2014, the master branch of Ransack has support for referencing scopes in search.

In my Gemfile,

```
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
```

In my model,

```
scope :starts_with_number, ->{ where("name  ~ '^(?![a-zA-Z])'") }

class << self
  def ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    [:starts_with_number]
  end
end
```

NOTE: The example scope above is written for Postgres.